# Find the minimal rows with maximum 1s column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy 2D array with all zeros and 1s and I want those rows that has atleast one 1 for each column. For example:

**PROBLEM STATEMENT:** Find minimal rows that gives maximum 1s across all columns.

**INPUT1:**

```
   A B C D E
t1 0 0 0 1 1
t2 0 1 1 0 1
t3 0 1 1 0 1
t4 1 0 1 0 1
t5 1 0 1 0 1
t6 1 1 1 1 0
```

Here, there are multiple answers like (t6, t1), (t6, t2), (t6, t3), (t6, t4), (t6, t5).

**INPUT2:**

```
   A B C D E
t1 0 0 0 1 1
t2 0 1 1 0 1
t3 0 1 1 0 1
t4 1 0 1 0 1
t5 1 0 1 0 1
t6 1 1 1 1 1
```

Answer: t6

I don't want to use brute force method as my original matrix is very big. Is there a smart way to do this?

Comment: Can you clarify? if a row has one "1" for each column in it, isn't it a row filled with "1"s?

Comment: @Sebastian: If a row has all 1s, in that case that's that row alone is the answer.

Comment: Why isn't (t4, t3, t1) a valid answer?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ (t4, t3, t1) can be a valid answer as well but I want minimal number of rows giving all 1s. So, (t1, t6) is one valid answer

Comment: Your title is completely off, it doesn't describe at all your problem...

Comment: I think I get what you're asking, though I think it could be clearer... I don't see a way around brute force. But I will think about it...

Comment: This is the [set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem).

Comment: I believe this to be a NP problem and brute-force is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Naive solution, worst-case O(2^n)

This iterates over all possible choices of rows, starting with as few rows as possible, making average cases usually low-polynomial time.

```
from itertools import combinations
import numpy as np

def minimum_rows(arr):
    out_list = []
    rows = arr.shape[0]
    for x in range(1, rows):
        for combo in combinations(range(rows),x):
            if np.logical_or.reduce(arr[[combo]]).all():
                out_list.append(combo)
        if out_list:
            return out_list
```

I wrote this entirely on my phone without much testing, so it may or may not work. It employs no tricks, but is fairly fast. Note that it will be slower when the ratio `columns/rows` is larger or the the probability of a given element being `True` is smaller, as that makes it less likely for fewer rows to meet the conditions required, causing `x` to increase, which in turn will increase the number of combinations iterated though.